# how to binary search in java

Tags: java, if-statement, binary-search

```
public class ArrayUtilities {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 30, 32 };
        int target1 = 30;
        System.out.println(binarySearch(array1, target1));
    }

    public static boolean binarySearch(int[] array, int target) {
        int left = 0;
        int right = array.length - 1;
        while (right >= left) {
            int middle = (right - left) / 2;
            if (target == array[middle]) {
                return true;
            } else if (target > array[middle]) {
                left = middle - 1;
            } else if (target < array[middle]) {
                right = middle + 1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Whenever i run the code, it doesnt print anything and it does not say error neither. I dont understand why.
Please help!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with Arrays.binarySearch? (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: its a homework, i cant use any library method but thank you anyways!

Comment: you are wrong, it outputs at least `true` or `false`, you can use debugger to see what's happening during the execution

Comment: Unless algorithm is implemented incorrectly and there is an infinite loop (since it's not recursive, it will not throw an Error)

Comment: OK, let's say you've narrowed down the search so that `left` is 4 and `right` is 8.  What should `middle` be?  What will the above program set it to?

Comment: you shifting left and right in wrong direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is not implemented correctly;

Your code is running an infinite loop.

Places to consider:

> 1. `int middle = (right - left)/2;` should be `int middle = (right + left)/2;`
> 2. else if (target > array[middle]){
>          left = middle - 1;  should be `left = middle+1;` remember, you need to find the number in the next part of the array.
> 3. Similarly consider the logic here; else if (target < array[middle]){
>      right = middle + 1;   }